# Get routing information about a URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I've got an ASP.NET MVC website that needs to display user-provided URLs stored in the DB. The way they're displayed will be different depending on how that URL would be routed if that URL refers to the website itself.

For example, supposing the website is *foo.com*:

- URL stored in DB: foo.com/pie/3/nutrition

  - Controller is "pie"
  - Action is "nutrition"
  - ID is 3

The way the link is formatted depends on all three of these.

How would I extract this information correctly? Can I query the URL routing device?

Note: "Use a regular expression" type of answers don't interest me -- the site, action, or controller names could change, the website may be accessible through multiple site names and ports, etc...

Comment: In your example did you mean `Controller is "pie"` instead of `Controller is "foo"`?

Comment: @Darin: Oops, yes. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find the `RouteInfo` class illustrated in [`this blog`](http://www.scottschluer.com/creating-a-routedata-instance-from-a-url/) post useful:

```
public class RouteInfo
{
    public RouteData RouteData { get; private set; }

    public RouteInfo(Uri uri, string applicationPath)
    {
        RouteData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new InternalHttpContext(uri, applicationPath));
    }

    private class InternalHttpContext : HttpContextBase
    {
        private readonly HttpRequestBase request;
        public InternalHttpContext(Uri uri, string applicationPath)
        {
            this.request = new InternalRequestContext(uri, applicationPath);
        }

        public override HttpRequestBase Request 
        { 
            get { return this.request; } 
        }
    }

    private class InternalRequestContext : HttpRequestBase
    {
        private readonly string appRelativePath;
        private readonly string pathInfo;

        public InternalRequestContext(Uri uri, string applicationPath)
        {
            this.pathInfo = uri.Query;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(applicationPath) || !uri.AbsolutePath.StartsWith(applicationPath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                this.appRelativePath = uri.AbsolutePath.Substring(applicationPath.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                this.appRelativePath = uri.AbsolutePath;
            }
        }

        public override string AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath 
        { 
            get { return string.Concat("~", appRelativePath); } 
        }

        public override string PathInfo 
        { 
            get { return this.pathInfo; } 
        }
    }
}
```

You could use it like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://foo.com/pie/3/nutrition");
    RouteInfo routeInfo = new RouteInfo(uri, this.HttpContext.Request.ApplicationPath);

    RouteData routeData = routeInfo.RouteData;

    string controller = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
    string action = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
    string id = routeData.Values["id"] as string;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Very nice, I'll give this a look.

Answer (score 0):

From the section about unit testing in this: [scott guthrie blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing)

you can do something like this:

```
MockHttpContext httpContxt = new MockHttpContext("foo.com/pie/3/nutrition");
RouteData routeData = new routes.GetRouteData(httpContext);
```

where routes is the RouteCollection you used to initialize your routes in your application. Then you can interrogate routeData["controller"] etc

the post is about an early version of MVC, so the class names may have changed since then.

Comment: I had skimmed this article before but didn't really see how it helped -- MockHttpContext isn't an existing class, and I don't know where "routes" come from.

Comment: Typically you have a call to RegisterRoutes in Global.asax. The routes set in that method can be put into a RouteCollection. the variable routes in my code is a RouteCollection. You may be able to use a real HttpContext in your code, or find a way to mock it.